# Different groupId (and version) for a same Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jitpack

I have a project in which a Maven project is deployed in two different ways using two `groupId`s and different `version`s. For example:

a) Depends on a branch (using [jitpack](http://jitpack.io)):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.user</groupId>
        <artifactId>myProj</artifactId>
        <version>aaaaaa-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

b) Depends on a ... version (other source):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.user</groupId>
        <artifactId>myProj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using method a). My project also depends on some other project which deploys method b). I don't know, how can I override the b) or how can I tell Maven that these are same project and ask them to use a).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092085/building-same-project-in-maven-with-different-artifactid-based-on-jdk-used) provides a way to use same project with different artefact names using `classifier`. I also looked on [Dependency Management](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176095/1359166) but could not really understand. I am not an expert in this field.

Comment: Just a hint a `-SNAPSHOT` is not a release...

Comment: FYI: "_a) Depends on a branch_" – Maven projects depend on artefacts (`jar`, `war`, etc.), not on (SCM) branches. `aaaaaa-SNAPSHOT` is an unusual version, see [Understanding Maven Version Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855). "_b) ..._ `<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`" is _not_ a release but a snapshot (i.e. development) version. `<type>jar` and `<scope>compile` aren't necessary to be declared explicitely since these are the defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to Maven, the two dependencies are different and hence cannot be overridden.

But you can use [`exclusions`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions) (detailed description in [Optional Dependencies and Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions)) to remove any transitive dependency.

Comment: hmmm.. possibly right. I can use `exclusion` for the method b).  If, I am not wrong, it would work if I use version 1.1.0 and exclude 1.0.0. Right? But, I want to completely ignore 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Probably, this is not really easy (or not possible at all).