# How to deal with multiple versions of a jar in a maven based java application?

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a maven project based java library that has a dependency on spring. What if this library is used by maven project based java projects that themselves use different versions of spring? Can that potentially cause problems? If yes, how to deal with it?

Comment: Of course that is likely to cause issues. There is no need to create a new version of a jar, unless the java version used changed, or if the implementation changed. This might cause serious problems. How to deal with it? Don't use different versions. Use one version. In your maven dependencies, exclude the version you don't want to use, keep the one you do want to use.

Comment: You might want to check this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176095/2915738) which seems to address a similar question